# Using color before flushleft adds vertical space

Tags: spacing, color

A `\color` command before a `\begin{flushleft}` adds spurious vertical space when compiled using `pdflatex` (see MWE). The documentation (`texdoc color`) mentions issues with spacing. Similar issues might apply to the `verbatim` environment.

Are there reliable solutions or workarounds for this problem that can be safely used for a [LaTeX code generator](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/264#issuecomment-6088003)? Or should one rather avoid, at all costs, switching color "between environments" -- say, by using the `fancyvrb` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

The spacing between this
\begin{flushleft}
and the following paragraph is good.
\end{flushleft}%
\color{red}%
\begin{flushleft} But here comes trouble. Why is the red block two parskips away?
\end{flushleft}
\color{blue}%
Changing from flushleft to regular doesn't add space even when color is changed.
\begin{flushleft} 
\color{green}%
Neither does changing color inside flushleft.
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The behaviour is not specific to pdfLateX -- it's the same for XeLaTeX.

Comment: The problem is that the `\color` instruction doesn't allow the mechanism for merging the space after and before the `flushleft` environments to act correctly.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you. Just out of curiosity: Perhaps the "mechanism for merging the space" can be altered to support `\color`? How does this work anyway? Which layer implements it?

Comment: I'm afraid that with the current LaTeX it's not possible. The `flushleft` environment emits an `\addvspace{\topskip}` command that examines what comes before it; if it's a skip, then the result will be, under normal conditions, the maximum of the two spaces. In this case, what comes before is a color declaration, which prevents the comparison.

Comment: Would it be possible to patch or enhance `\addvspace` so that it overlooks any `\color` commands?

Comment: No basically it isn't possible to look past color if you allow _any_ command to use any primitive TeX construct like a skip or a box or a penalty. tex has \lastskip and \lastpenalty primitives that allow you to see the last thing already placed on the list but there is no \lastspecial or unspecial command to look past or remove a special (or other whatsit) once such a node is placed in a list the list is essentially opaque to TeX's later processing and can not be deconstructed.

Comment: As @Joseph hints in his comment on my answer, l3galley addresses this because the macro layer keeps track of everything, However it can only do this if nothing is allowed to add a skip or penalty or box to the vertical list except through the l3galley interface. (which means it is incompatible with everything that is not written for that interface)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes if at all possible you should generate

```
\begin{flushleft} 
\leavevmode\color{red} But here comes trouble. Why is the red block two parskips away?
\end{flushleft}
```

So the colour whatsit is found inside the first line rather than before the paragraph, sorry that's just how it is.

Comment: Unless of course you load `l3galley` and add whatsits using its mechanism :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanation in the comments.